# How to set NavigationView default value?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI


struct DetailView: View {
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    private let names = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    @State private var selection: String? = "One"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(text: name)) {
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
            }

            DetailView(text: "Make a selection")
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I thought that setting 'selection' to 'One' is the answer but it only makes 'One' highlighted (with grey color by the way). 
[image]

The desired behaviour on startup is:
[image]

Comment: List supports multiselections.

Comment: Just don't see your problem. Maybe need to update to latest Xcode

Comment: @E.Coms I have Xcode 11.3 Build version 11C29

Comment: Works with Xcode 11.2.1 / macOS 10.15.2 (except known grey highlight issue)

Comment: Are you using an iPad simulator? and what's the detailView?

Comment: @E.Coms No. It's macos. Updated code snippet with detail view.

Comment: Wait. Do I have to change "DetailView(text: "Make a selection")" with something like "DetailView(text: self.selection ?? "Make a selection")"? It works, but I thought that NavigationView will handle this by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work adding the selection in the placeholder `selection ?? "Make a selection"`, i.e:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let names = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    @State private var selection: String? = "One"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(text: name)) {
                        Text(name)
                    }
                }
            }

            DetailView(text: selection ?? "Make a selection")
        }
    }
}
```